# How To Train Stanford NER For Names That Include Spaces?

Tags: named-entity-recognition

The [example training excersize](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.html#d) labels single-term names after tokenizing with something like a simple `split(' ')`.

I need to train for and recognize names that include spaces. How do I train the recognizer?

Example: "I saw a Big Red Apple Tree." -- How would I tokenize for training and then recognize "Big Red Apple Tree" instead of recognizing four separate words?

Will this work for the training data?

```
I\tO
saw\tO
a\tO
Big Red Apple Tree\tMyName
.\tO
```

Would the output from the recognizer look the same as that?

The training section in the FAQ says *"The training file parser isn't very forgiving: You should make sure each line consists of solely content fields and tab characters. Spaces don't work."*

Comment: The output wont look like that because the classifer will recognize each and every word. You need to train your data in such a way that you get `Big Red Apple Tree` all the words as `MyName`

Comment: Hi Joe , i have the same problem.have found out the solution.if yes can you please share the solution?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are trying to solve belongs to phrase identification. There are different ways with which you can tag the words. For example, You can tag the words with [IOB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside_Outside_Beginning) tags. Train the stanford ner model onto this newly created data. Write a post processing step to concatenate the predicted data.

For Example :
your training data should look like this:

```
I\tO
saw\tO
a\tO
Big\tB-MyName
Red\tI-MyName
Apple\tI-MyName
Tree\tO-MyName
.\tO<br/>
```

So Basically, you are using `[ 0, B-MyName , I-MyName , O-MyName ]` as tags.
I have solved similar problem and it works great. But make sure you have enough data to train it on.